# Angularjs: how to pass $filter to function in case of "controller as" syntax?

Tags: angularjs

I am new to AngularJS. I am trying to work out an example of a SportsStore app from a book I am following.

In this app, there are several categories of products. Categories are also displayed on the left side of the view.

[image]

Clicking a "category" is going to filter the products by category and is going to highlight the Category button.

Reading tutorials on net I understand that the "controller as" syntax is being favored over the "$scope" syntax.

How do I pass a filter (categoryFilterFn) to my controller function for filtering the products by category?

***app.html***

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html ng-app="SportsStoreApp">
  <head>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.js"></script>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular-resource.js"></script>
   <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
   <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
   <script src='app.js'></script>
   <script src='customFilters.js'></script>
   <script src='productListControllers.js'></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="SportsStoreCtrl as controller">
   <div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">SPORTS STORE</a>
   </div>
   <div class="panel panel-default row" ng-controller="ProductListCtrl">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
     <a ng-click="selectCategory()"
      class="btn btn-block btn-default btn-lg">Home</a>
     <a ng-repeat="item in controller.data.products | orderBy:'category' | unique_selection:'category'"
      ng-click="selectCategory(item)" class=" btn btn-block btn-default btn-lg"
      ng-class="getCategoryClass(item)">
      {{item}}
     </a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-8">
     <div class="well" ng-repeat="item in controller.data.products | filter:categoryFilterFn">
      <h3>
       <strong>{{item.name}}</strong>
       <span class="pull-right label label-primary">
        {{item.price | currency}}
       </span>
      </h3>
      <span class="lead">{{item.description}}</span>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </body>
 </html>
```

***customFilters.js***

```js
angular.module("customFilters", [])
.filter("unique_selection", function(){
 return function(data, propertyName) {
  if (angular.isArray(data) && angular.isString(propertyName)) {
   var results = [];
   var keys = {};
   for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var val = data[i][propertyName];
    if (angular.isUndefined(keys[val])) {
     keys[val] = true;
     results.push(val);
    }
   }
   return results;
  } else {
   return data;
  }
 }
});
```

***app.js***

```js
var app = angular.module("SportsStoreApp", ['customFilters']);

app.controller("SportsStoreCtrl", function(){
 this.data = {
  products: [
   { name: "Product #1", description: "A product",
    category: "Category #1", price: 100 },
   { name: "Product #2", description: "A product",
    category: "Category #1", price: 110 },
   { name: "Product #3", description: "A product",
    category: "Category #2", price: 210 },
   { name: "Product #4", description: "A product",
    category: "Category #3", price: 202 }
  ]
 }; 
});
```

***productListControllers.js***

```js
angular.module("SportsStoreApp")
 .constant('productListActiveClass', "btn-primary")
 .controller('ProductListCtrl', function($scope, $filter, productListActiveClass) {
  var selectedCategory = null;

  $scope.selectCategory = function(newCategory) {
   selectedCategory = newCategory;
  };

  $scope.categoryFilterFn = function(product) {
   return selectedCategory == null ||
      product.category == selectedCategory;
  };

  $scope.getCategoryClass = function(category) {
   return selectedCategory = category ? productListActiveClass : "";
  };
 });
```

In productListControllers.js, how do I not use "$scope" object and use "this" object along with "$filter" argument? Also, how can I use "ProductListCtrl as product_ctrl" in app.html?

Comment: Your example mixes two controllers, one with "controllerAs" syntax, the other with legacy syntax. This is going to drive us and you crazy. Adopt only one syntax and use it for all the controllers. Feel free to use simple instance names like `vm`, `vm2`, etc. that will leave the template less cluttered.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use your [`custom filter`](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter#creating-custom-filters) inside a controller, simply inject your custom filter into your controller using the name of your filter and the suffix `Filter`.

In your instance you need to inject `unique_selectionFilter`. You can then use it in your controller passing in your data and property name values:

```
unique_selectionFilter(data, propertyName)
```

Alternatively you can inject the [`$filter`](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter) service and access your filter through it by passing in it's name:

```
$filter('unique_selection')(data, propertyName)
```